# Removing paragraphs from multiple text files

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, iteration

Let's say we have a certain directory which contains multiple text files. Each text file has 3 paragraphs separated by blank lines like this:

Paragraph_1

Paragraph_2

Paragraph_3

Is there a way to remove everything below Paragraph_1 for each text file using a python script or a UNIX command (without having to create new files)? 
If it helps, Paragraph_2 of each text file starts the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In POSIX shell

```sh
for f in file1 file2; do
    sed -e '/^$/Q' "$f"
done
```

prints the first paragraph of each file to standard output. The first part, `/^$/`, of the sed command is a label that triggers on an empty line, the `Q` makes sed quit processing any further lines. If you want to preserve the empty line, use `q`. If you want to modify the files in-place, pass the `-i` flag to sed.

Comment: It's good... it's very good...

Answer (score 0):

With a python script, you could find the things you want to remove, and then add everything else:

```
def m():
  with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    lines_to_remove = []
    for i in d:
        if i != "Paragraph_2\n":
            lines_to_remove.append(i)
        else:
            break
    for i in d:
        print(i not in lines_to_remove)
        if(i not in lines_to_remove):
            f.write(i)
```